# Neo4j calculate delta between two queries results

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm working on an Access management system and now I have the challenge to detect the delta of permissions gained and lost for each modification of the current authorization.
So, I was thinking to create a parallel graph with different LABELS that represent the previous state.
I'm trying to execute my query to get all the permissions and target population for both graphs and then calculate the delta.
This is the query I use to get the permissions and for each permission its target population (people on who the user can use the permission upon):

```
match (u:UserPrevious {Id: '1', GraphTenantId: '685bff85-2759-204a-afa7-f6ba516c4f9f'})
with u
match (u)-[:IS_ACCESS_USER|BELONG_TO|IS_ACCESS_GROUP*1..2]->(ra:RoleAssignmentPrevious),
(ra)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(rl:RolePrevious)-[:CONTAINS_PERM]->(permission:PermissionPrevious) with distinct u, ra, permission
match (ra)-[:IS_TARGET]->(tg:TargetGroupPrevious)
with distinct tg, permission
match (target:UserPrevious)<-[*1..2]-(tg)
Where (target)<-[:HAS_HIERARCHICAL_ACCESS|HAS_HIERARCHICAL*1..2]-(tg)
With distinct permission.ShortName as p1, collect(distinct target.ReferenceId) as targets1
Return distinct p1, targets1
```

How can I execute the same query for another userId and then calculate the delta? It means firstly what permission the user lost or gained, and then for each permission the targets that the user lost and gained.
My feeling is that this won't have good performance.
Is there something that can help me or maybe I should solve this problem out of Neo4j database?